# The way to modify android libraries

Tags: android

I need to modify some codes which belong in android internal library(`BluetoothAdapter.java`)

And I know such that behavior is not recommended according to the android but I need that.

I made a method in `BluetoothAdapter.java` for testing and tried to access that method but it was not able to find. And clean project and rebuild project also had no effect.
After that, I opened `BluetoothAdapter.java` file with other editor and checked that code has been changed well. But I don't know how to compile with my project.

Please share your ideas.

Comment: It uses internal `BluetoothAdapter.java` from the device firmware. To modify it, you will need to modify your device's firmware. When you build the app, it does not include entire Android framework into your APK, it uses pre-installed framework from the device itself. Therefore you can't modify it using your APK.

Comment: how about create your custom class extending the class your wanted to modify and override the method you need to change?

Comment: @MichaelLam this won't work, as it won't make Android OS to use the custom extended class.

Comment: @Vladyslav Matviienko Ok I see. I will try in other way.

Comment: @Michael Lam Good idea. But in my case, The code in my project which I am not able to access that is using functions which is in BluetoothAdapter.java. So I have to modify that library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses internal BluetoothAdapter.java from the device firmware. To modify it, you will need to modify your device's firmware. When you build the app, it does not include entire Android framework into your APK, it uses pre-installed framework from the device itself. Therefore you can't modify it using your APK. – Vladyslav Matviienko